# Webpack: How to inject process.env runtime on client(browser) side making build independent of environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-4

**SHORT Question**

I'm looking some way to tell Webpack that, do not do anything with `process` variable, just treat as like any other global variable (so it refers to window.process in client bundle). If not possible, then a way to inject variables in `process.env` of Webpack during runtime on client.

**LONG Explaination**

At the moment, I use Webpack to pack my React (SSR) application. I have 5 environments like dev1, dev2... staging and production. I want to re-use the same build and keep things configurable like say Google Analytics ID on each environment is different.

Backend Dot ENV module does the job. I can define all constants as `KEY=value` pair in `.env` file and load them run time and use as `process.env.KEY` in the code.

I was trying to replicate same behaviour for the front end side (or shared files). Say I have a `baseService.js` which makes call to `fetch`. It can be used from node + client as well. It uses variables like `process.env.HOST`. Until now I was creating separate build for each environment, therefore had this defined in Webpack using `webpack.DefinePlugin` plugin to be able to use this on client side bundle.

Now as I want to re-use the builds, I capture all constants in `process.env` see if any of them is usable on client side by matching them with `PUBLIC_(.*)` (It would match PUBLIC_KEY), if yes pack then in array and add in main html file as object as shown below:-

```
window.process = {ENV: { PUBLIC_GA_ID: '1235', PUBLIC_FOO: 'bar' }}
```

When I bundle my client using webpack and execute `process.env.PUBLIC_GA_ID` is undefined (although it is there in head html as global `window.process` variable). It is because webpack still injecting process variable from Node to the front end which has `env` object as blank `{}` object. I had it debugged below is the screenshot.

[image]

Above is console log of `process` variable in a `baseService.js` file. Obviously I cannot use `window.process` here because then it would fail when file is being used in Node.js

I'm looking some way to tell Webpack that, do not do anything with `process` variable, just treat as like any other global variable (so it refers to window.process in client bundle). If not possible, then a way to inject variables in `process.env` of Webpack during runtime on client.

Comment: Did you checkout the EnvironmentPlugin? https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/

Comment: @ben That writes up values at compile time example process.env. PUBLIC_FOO will become `bar` compile time itself. So this is not re-usable build as this value may be different for other environment. I'm looking for runtime option

Comment: @UmakantPatil let an answer, trying to do exactly what you want to. It worked in that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think instead playing with Webpack to do this job, I have settled with for the simplest solution. If anyone has any better answer, please do post.

I created a utility function as follows:-

```
export const getEnv = key => {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    // node
    return process.env[key]
  }
  // browser
  return window.process.env[key]
}
```

Now I call `getEnv('PUBLIC_KEY')` or `getEnv('NODE_ENV')` both in node and in browser and works perfectly fine.

Although I'd still prefer the better way Webpack supports option to take `process.env` run time or inject API for browser

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with webpack inlining the contents of `process.env.NODE_ENV` at compile time.

I was able to switch that off by adding the following to my server webpack config:

```
  optimization: {
    nodeEnv: 'production'
  }
```

[See the optimization docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationnodeenv) for more related info

Answer (score 2):

Use "[globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)" in your code in place of "window" and use "[globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis).process" in place of "process".

Answer (score 0):

In fact, webpack preset 2 environment to build different app.
Consider this config:

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "build:development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack",
    "build:production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production  webpack",
 }
```

```js
// webpack.config.js
const ENVIRONMENT = process.env.NODE_ENV;
module.exports = {
entry: { // ... },
output: { // ... },

// typeof mode =  "development" | "production" | "none";
mode: ENVIRONMENT

}
```

`$ npm run build:development`

After building, open browser, also output that you set `current env is: development`
good luck

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is:

- Use webpack to generate the bundle, that will be reused in dev, prod, stage.
- Access the .env file in execution time, with your own code and not using dotenv, neither webpack-dotenv.
- create a function getEnv() that uses  `const rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();` and reads your .env file.
- you don't use dotenv package, neither you require it. You just import { getEnv }  and use it in your code in runtime.

Of course this is not the safest, but either dotenv or webpack-dotenv are since the keys are being injected to the client anyways and accessible.

And you can reuse your bundle, and create the file that your function reads in the docker, or anywhere.