# Can we override webpack DefinePlugin 's variable in React application

Tags: reactjs, webpack

For a React application that is built with webpack, using DefinePlugin like this

```
plugins: options.plugins.concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        REACT_APP_BASE_URL: JSON.stringify("my-url"),
      },
      'anotherVar': {
        REACT_APP_BASE_URL: JSON.stringify("my-url"),
      },
    }),
  ]),
```

My question is how / at which place can we override that variable `process.env = anotherVar` at *the earliest possible moment*

The React application is simply loaded like this

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
render(
   <App />
,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

More context of what I am trying to accomplish can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68296875/reactjs-strategy-to-replace-webpack-environment-variable-at-deploy-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much time searching I found that it is not possible. Webpack embed the object as string at build-time. There is no possibility to change anything at run-time

[Can't set values on `process.env` in client-side Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871895/cant-set-values-on-process-env-in-client-side-javascript)

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61408502/webpack-how-to-inject-process-env-runtime-on-clientbrowser-side-making-build) seems to provide an alternative to have dynamic process.env